# How can I fix pthread_mutex_trylock error in Android

Tags: android, c++, cmake, pthreads

I have a Problem on an emulated Android device. To be honest on every emulated Android Device. There is a mutex test from Android Bionic. It could be found under:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/froyo/tests/bionic/libc/bionic/test_mutex.c

So, when compiling this with CMake and the Android Toolchain for Android x86 or x86_64 it compiles fine.
Altough, when running the file it throws an error in line 90:

```
    expect( pthread_mutex_trylock( &lock ), EDEADLK );
```

The error message:

```
generic_x86_arm:/data/local # ./test_mutex
/home/tjk/coding/oorexx/mutex/test_mutex.c:80: call returned 16 instead of 35: pthread_mutex_trylock( &lock )
```

If I delete this on line everything is fine and I get an "ok". Thats not a solution because I'm working on a big project and debugging tells me that there are problems and its very likely that the trylock function is the reason for that. So I need to fix that. The mutex test has to work.

What can I do? What could be the reason for that? Is it the device? Is it the Android Toolchain or is there something wrong with my CMake Command? My CMake Command:

```
cmake -H./ -B./build2 -DANDROID_NDK=~/coding/android-ndk-r22b/ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/coding/android-ndk-r22b/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI="x86" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \                            (base) 
                                                                        -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$CC -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$CXX -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=30
```

The CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6.0)
project(test_mutex)
add_executable(test_mutex test_mutex.c)
```

I would really appreciate any useful tips. Thank you!

Best Regards Thomas

Comment: According to the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), in case the mutex is already locked by the current thread, `pthread_mutex_trylock` shall (must) return `EBUSY`(16) and this is what you observe. `EDEADLK`(35) may be returned by other function, `pthread_mutex_lock`.

Comment: So the ouput is what I want? It never finishes the test in this scenario. are you sure? Because in the end the testfile should output "OK" if I understand correctly. See:

```
printf( "ok\n" );
    return 0;
```

Comment: sorry for being suspicious. you are absolutely right. so the problem is with the program itself. i have now changed the expectation value to EBUSY and then of course it works. Thank you very much! Best Thomas

Comment: It was just my thoughts. I don't know what is intended behavior of Android.

Comment: For the love of god, please switch to C++ threads. Tell us what you are trying to do and we can help with that.